Abelian group with maximal number of subgroups of order 18

Among all the abelian groups of order 21600 find one that has the
maximal number of subgroups of order 18. Decompose this group into
primary groups.

Here's my attempt: $21600 = 3^3 2^5 5^2$, so the group $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ has order $21600$ and it has subgroups $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Now this is the group we need because we can have at most two different subgroups of order 18 at the same time here.
Is this argument correct? I feel like there is a mistake right in the middle but can't see it. Can you help me understand the decomposition into primary subgroups?

$\mathbb{Z}_6\cong \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Why are the other copies broken out, but not this one?

You can have a lot more than two groups of order $18$ at the same time. $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ has three.

As pointed out in the comments, it is possible to have several subgroups of order $18$. First, notice that the $5$-part of the group doesn't matter, so we only need to look at abelian groups of order $2^5 \cdot 3^3$. Let the $2$-part and $3$-part of the abelian group be $P$ and $Q$, then $G \cong P \times Q$.
Now, an order $18$ subgroup can be uniquely specified by its order $2$ subgroup and its order $9$ subgroup. We have thus broken our problem down into two subproblems: finding the $P$ with the most subgroups of order $2$ and finding the $Q$ with the most subgroups of order $9$.

$2$-Part: Do you see why $P \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^5$ will give you the maximal number of order $2$ subgroups? (Hint: What is a simple way to describe an order $2$ subgroup?)
$3$-Part: You can do this directly by looking at all possibilities for $Q$ (there are only three!). However, here is an idea to minimize your work, let's think of our problem as maximizing the number of index $3$ subgroups instead. Since every index $3$ subgroup of $Q$ must contain $3Q$, we wish to maximize the number of index $3$ subgroups in $Q/3Q$. However, $Q/3Q$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$, so we are trying to maximize its codimension $1$ subspaces. This is achieved by maximizing the dimension of $Q/3Q$. Do you see what choice of $Q$ achieves this?

Remark: Technically, the same argument for the $3$-Part also applies to the $2$-Part after you use the numerical version of "Pontryagin duality" (i.e. the number of order $2$ and index $2$ subgroups are equal).

Am I correct in saying that $Q$ should be $(\mathbb{Z}_3)^3$?

That's correct!

Now for $P$ we can say that we want to get as many elements of order 2 as possible, right? Then we have to make it $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^5$

Yep, perfect :)

am I correct in saying that there will be $5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$ groups of order 18 in $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^5 \times (\mathbb{Z}_3)^2 \times \mathbb{Z}_25$? This follows because we can choose $5$ different $2$'s and $6$ different pairs of $3$'s.

No, that's not exactly right. Don't be fooled by the exponent since that is just counting the copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you are using for coordinates. For $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^5$, try counting the number of order-$2$ elements. Can you try something similar for $(\mathbb{Z}_3)^3$ using duality? Be careful in this case about scaling!
